Search exact string match over multiple fields Opensearch
I'm trying to get all documents that have a specific value in one or more fields. I'm currently using Opensearch v2.13.
Here's my mapping :
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "knn": true
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            ...Some other properties...
            "parent_id": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "link": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}

And my query :
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_id": ":id"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "parent_id": ":id"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "parent_id"
  ]
}

Problem : I have no document with the :id in the parent_id field while some exist in the database. I tried to add a clause to check if the field parent_id is present because not all documents contain that field, but it doesn't work either. Any idea why ?
